# Python, Creating Parallel Lists from a Text File

Tags: python, list, text-files

I currently have the text file (values on each line are separated by a tab):

```
1935    32.1
1940    30.5
1945    24.4
1950    23.0
1955    19.1
1960    15.6
1965    12.4
1970    9.7
1975    8.9
1980    7.2
```

And ultimately I wish to create two parallel lists such that:

```
listX=[1935, 1940, 1945, 1950, 1955, 1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 1980]
listY=[32.1, 30.5, 24.4, 23.0, 19.1, 15.6, 12.4, 9.7, 8.9, 7.2]
```

For whatever reason I'm drawing a blank on this one. What would be the best way to go about creating these separate lists?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: There are probably thousands of similar questions. At the very least, you should try to find such a question and try the approach, and if you can't get it to work, then ask a question that *highlights how your attempts have not worked*. They key for a question like this is describing what you've tried and how it's failed. This is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with the x and y being tuples, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#zip):

```
import io
with io.open('file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   x, y = zip(* (l.split() for l in line))
```

If it has to be lists, either convert the tuples to lists:

```
with io.open('file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   x, y = map(list(zip(* (l.split() for l in line))))
```

or pluck the values by hand:

```
with io.open('file.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   values = [l.split() for l in line]
x = [v[0] for v in values]
y = [v[1] for v in values]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = open('file.txt').readlines()

listX = [d.split('\t')[0] for d in data]
listY = [d.split('\t')[1] for d in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "r+")
str = fo.read()
# If you have a new line character at the end
str = str[:len(str)-1]
a = str.split('\n')
b = []
d = []
for i in a:
    x = i.split('\t')
    b.append(x[0])
    d.append(x[1])
```

b and d would be your required lists.